# How do I detect a Composite Primary Key in Grails 3.0?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0, grails-3.0.10

I am currently migrating a Grails 2.4 project to Grails 3.0.10 or 3.1.0.M3.

In Grails 2.4, the following method is a workaround that allows me to detect whether a Domain Class features a composite primary key:

```
void isCompositePrimaryKey(GrailsDomainClass targetClass) {
    def binder = new GrailsDomainBinder()
    def idMapping = binder.getMapping(targetClass).identity
    return idMapping instanceof org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.CompositeIdentity
}
```

I cannot find a way to detect this in the Public API.

Though GrailsDomainClass still exists in the implementation source code, I cannot seem to access it from my project nor can I find the old CompositeIdentity.

An alternative strategy could be via `targetClass.getIdentifier().getType()`
but I cannot find any documentation on how to detect a composite key using the identity type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this simply by adding an additional explicit (non-transitive) dependency to `build.gradle` for the Hibernate 4 GORM implementation package.

(I determined the package and version by looking in the local gradle files cache but `gradle dependencies` would also have worked.)

Added to `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:5.0.0.RC2'`
```

This allows access to the internal API, then the above method still works.

NB. The GORM developers also advise that there is existing GORM API for this, via the `PersistentEntity` and `MappingContext` classes without using `GrailsDomainClass`.